# How to make @Query perform ContainingIgnoreCase function in JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I have made a @Query in JPA that returns the all values of a table that are related to a table according to its name but I would like it to work as a ContainingIgnoreCase, I have tried LIKE but it gives me an error.

```
@Query("select v from Variedad v "
            + "join v.especie e "
            + "where v.dtype='Variedad' "
            + "and e.nombre = :nombreEspecie "
//          + "like %?1%"
            + "order by v.nombre asc")
Page<Variedad> listarTodosFiltradoPorNombreEspecie(String nombreEspecie, Pageable pagina);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add IgnoreCase at the end of the method, so JPA will do the job for you (as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)? Also, you can try to modify your SQL as such "... UPPER(e.nombre) = UPPER(:nombreEspecie) ...".